# error: Non-nullable instance field 'pickedImage' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

error: Non-nullable instance field 'pickedImage' must be initialized.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  File pickedImage;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use nullable operator `?` here.

Your code should be as following..

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  File? pickedImage;
...
```